# Access pointer array inside pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to create a method called **add_order** to add a new order to an existing orders array. The first 3 lines in the main is working fine, until that point I understand pointers, but with the add_order method I'm struggling with it, it's not working in the printf either. How can I access a pointer array inside a pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int count;
  char type;
} *pizza;

typedef struct {
  int courier;
  int day;
  pizza p;
} *order;

typedef struct {
  order orders;
  int orderCount;
} *monthlyorders;

monthlyorders new_monthlyorders(order o) {
  monthlyorders m = malloc(sizeof(monthlyorders));
  m->orders = malloc(sizeof(order));
  m->orders = o;
  m->orderCount = 0;
  return m;
}

order new_order(int courier, int day, pizza p) {
  order o = malloc(sizeof(order));
  o->courier = courier;
  o->day = day;
  o->p = malloc(sizeof(pizza));
  o->p = p;
  return o;
}

pizza new_pizza(int count, char type) {
  pizza pizza = malloc(sizeof(pizza));
  pizza->count = count;
  pizza->type = type;
  return pizza;
}

monthlyorders add_order(monthlyorders m, order o) {
  m->orderCount = (m->orderCount)+1;
  (*(m->orders+1)) = malloc(sizeof(order));
  return m;
}

int main() {

  pizza p = new_pizza(2, 'A');
  order o = new_order(1, 1, p);
  monthlyorders m = new_monthlyorders(o);

  add_order(m, o);

  printf("%i\n", (*(m->orders+1)));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please restate this question ... perhaps in an "answer" ... to directly and specifically point out *the* lines of source-code which represent your question.  Also, tell us what it's doing now.

Comment: do not typedef poiters. It makes code very hard to read. Declarations are not clear

Comment: I know, but it's a uni homework and I have to create the methods exactly like this. That's why I have to write them for the typedef.

Comment: When I was studying, and they asked me to do something silly - I was arguing explaining my point of view.

Comment: Then you will need to replace `order o = malloc(sizeof(order));` with `order o = malloc(sizeof(*o));` and similarly for the other `malloc` calls. Because you only have typedefs for the pointer types and the pointed to types are all anonymous, the only way you have to get the correct size is by sizeof(*pointer_variable). The fact that you have no way to re-use the underlying types of the pointer types is bad programming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use pointers correctly. You most likely forgot to make 'orders' as a pointer. Let me know if it solves your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int count;
  char type;
} *pizza;

typedef struct {
  int courier;
  int day;
  pizza p;
} *order;

typedef struct {
  order * orders; // order * orders -> create a pointer
  int orderCount;
} *monthlyorders;

order new_order(int courier, int day, pizza p) {
  order o = malloc(sizeof(order));
  o->courier = courier;
  o->day = day;
  o->p = malloc(sizeof(pizza));
  o->p = p;
  return o;
}

pizza new_pizza(int count, char type) {
  pizza pizza = malloc(sizeof(pizza));
  pizza->count = count;
  pizza->type = type;
  return pizza;
}

monthlyorders add_order(monthlyorders m, order o) {
  *(m->orders + m->orderCount) = o;
  m->orderCount++;
  return m;
}

monthlyorders new_monthlyorders(order o) {
  monthlyorders m = malloc(sizeof(monthlyorders));
  m->orders = malloc(1000); // You might need more cases (eg. 10000? )
  m->orderCount = 0;
  return add_order(m,o);
}

int main() {

  pizza p = new_pizza(2, 'A');
  order o = new_order(1, 1, p);
  monthlyorders m = new_monthlyorders(o);


  // Test cases
  order o2 = new_order(2, 1, p);
  add_order(m, o2);

  // You might want to print out data from your object rather than the object itself
  printf("%i\n", (*(m->orders))->courier);
  printf("%i\n", (*(m->orders))->day);
  printf("%i\n", (*(m->orders + 1))->courier);
  printf("%i\n", (*(m->orders + 1))->day);
  // Don't forget to free it
  free(m->orders);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Consider doing what Ian said: replace

```
order o = malloc(sizeof(order));
```

with

```
order o = malloc(sizeof(*o));
```

and similarly for the other malloc calls

Comment: @Natixco It may _appear_ to work, but most of the `malloc` calls are using the wrong size.